# TSQL Ranking using timestamp and datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to rank a series of transactions, however my source data does not capture the time of a transaction which can happen multiple times a day, the only other field I can use is a `timestamp` field - will this be ranked correctly?

Here's the code

```
SELECT [LT].[StockCode]
     , [LT].[Warehouse]
     , [LT].[Lot]
     , [LT].[Bin]
     , [LT].[TrnDate]
     , [LT].[TrnQuantity]
     , [LT].[TimeStamp] 
     , LotRanking = Rank() Over (Partition By [LT].[Warehouse],[LT].[StockCode],[LT].[Lot] Order By [LT].[TrnDate] Desc, [LT].[TimeStamp] Desc)
     From [LotTransactions] [LT]
```

Results being returned are as below

```
StockCode   |Warehouse  |Lot    |Bin    |TrnDate                    |TrnQuantity    |TimeStamp          |LotRanking
2090        |CB         |3036   |CB     |2016-02-16 00:00:00.000    |2.000000       |0x0000000000500AB9 |1
2090        |CB         |3036   |CB     |2016-02-16 00:00:00.000    |2.000000       |0x0000000000500A4E |2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to get `datetime` of transaction:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(50),[LT].[TrnDate],121),10) + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(50),CAST([LT].[TimeStamp] as datetime),121),13)
```

For first string it will be:

```
2016-02-16 04:51:25.417
```

And use this for ranking.

Comment: I understand the answer, but the upvote is curious.  The OP has pretty clearly stated that there is no time component on the date column.

Comment: There is no on `TrnDate` but `SELECT CAST(0x0000000000500AB9 as datetime)` from `TimeStamp` column gives this: `1900-01-01 04:51:25.417`.

Comment: I should add that treating `timestamp`/`rowversion` as an actual date, time, or datetime value is explicitly a bad idea in SQL Server.  Where do the upvotes come from?

Comment: Can I know from whom they are coming?! Yes, it is bad idea, but as OP commented *I cannot change the source data table as this is outside of my remit* so, he have to work with what he have.

Comment: @gofr1 thanks for this, I appreciate that it's not an even close to an ideal dataset but this does give me something I can use to add a level of ranking for displaying data, with the knowledge that it's only really as accurate as the day.

Comment: @ChrisJ . . . From the perspective of your original query, this is just an overcomplication.  Using your original formulation with two keys is simpler and functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should be using `rowversion` rather than `timestamp` for keeping track of row versioning information.  I believe `timestamp` is deprecated.  At the very least, the documentation explicitly suggests `[rowversion][1]`.

Second, I would strongly recommend that you add an identity column to the table.  This will provide the information that you really need -- as well as a nice unique key for the table.

In general, a `timestamp` or `rowversion` is used just to determine whether or not a row has changed -- not to determine the ordering.  But, based on this description, what you are doing might be correct:

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or
>   update operation that is performed on a table that contains a
>   timestamp column within the database. This counter is the database
>   timestamp. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an
>   actual time that can be associated with a clock. A table can have only
>   one timestamp column. Every time that a row with a timestamp column is
>   modified or inserted, the incremented database timestamp value is
>   inserted in the timestamp column.

I would caution that this might not be safe.  Instead, it gives a reason why such an approach might make sense.  Let me repeat the recommendation:  add an identity column, so you are correctly adding this information, at least for the future.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the source data table as this is outside of my remit, otherwise your suggestions would be ideal